# AutoPost capture what caused it.

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code in my .aspx file:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Width="278px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

When I click on the btnSearch button it does an AutoPostBack.

What my goal is that if btnSearch was clicked, I would then capture the value of txtSearch or else I would not

How do I code such that if btnSearch was clicked on AutoPost I can flag it.

Comment: Basically you want the default behaviour : if a user submits a form through the button, the form is posted to the server. you don't need autopostback, especially as a button is not an autopostback : you click on it. Autopostback is to be used to submit when a user fills/changes an input for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.aspx) [does not have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button_properties.aspx) an `AutoPostBack` property. It posts back always.

Second, you can simply handle it's [`Click` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) and read the `txtSearch.Text` property:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Width="278px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

codebehind:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string search = txtSearch.Text;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. How do I put this in  if (Page.IsPostBack){  }. How can I tell if btnSearch was clicked.

Comment: @NatePet: Why do you need to know somewhere else than in the button's click-event handler(above) that it was clicked? I assume that you are doing too much in `Page_Load`. Use the appropriate events instead. And databind only if `!IsPostBack`. In twelve years of ASP.NET development i never needed to check `if(Page.IsPostBack)` but only vice-versa.